# Trying to work with classes (SDL)

Tags: c++, sdl

My problem is that I do not know how to relate to function GetTexture and struct         SDL_Rect * rect (public), members of class Texture

inside Main class private section I declared:

```
Texture box("textures/box.png",100, 100, 20, 20);
```

The following phrase was put inside Main class MainLoop function:

```
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, box.GetTexture(), NULL, box->rect);
```

The line throws errors:

```
\Main.cpp|28|error: '((Main*)this)->Main::box' does not have class type|

\Main.cpp|28|error: invalid use of member function (did you forget the '()' ?)|

\Main.cpp|28|error: base operand of '->' is not a pointer|
```

This is Texture.h code:

```
#ifndef TEXTURE_H
#define TEXTURE_H
#include <string>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>

using namespace std;

class Texture
{
    public:
        Texture(string path, int x, int y, int w, int h);
        virtual ~Texture();

        SDL_Texture GetTexture();

        SDL_Rect * rect; 
    protected:
    private:
        SDL_Texture * texture; 
};

#endif // TEXTURE_H
```

And Texture.cpp:

```
#include "Texture.h"

using namespace std;

Texture::Texture(string path, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    texture = NULL;
    texture = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, path.c_str()); 
    rect.x = x;
    rect.y = y;
    rect.w = w;
    rect.h = h;
}

Texture::~Texture()
{
    //dtor
}

SDL_Texture Texture::GetTexture()
{
    return texture;
}
```

I'm little bit confused, probably just haven't understood objective programming at all yet. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The -> operator is used to access members of pointers, not to access pointers members of a non-pointer object. So you should use:

```
box.rect
```

And the way you do it should be used if box would be a pointer.

```
Texture* box = new Texture;
box->rect
```

Comment: It helped, pointer error solved. But there is still problem with: 
 \Main.cpp|28|error: '((Main*)this)->Main::box' does not have class type| - it occurs 2 times

Comment: Oh right, you declared box as a function because you used (). You should declare it like this: Texture box; and initialize it in cpp file or in the header using {}. http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#uniform-init